# OnUpdate() called before OnInitialUpdate()

Tags: c++, mfc

I thought that `OnInitialUpdate()` function called before `OnUpdate()` function, but when I open the document, `OnInitialUpdate()` called first but after this `CView::OnInitialUpdate();` it calls `OnUpdate()`. So, it couldn't go to the next step further after this `CView::OnInitialUpdate();` before executing `OnUpdate()` function.

```
void PinNameView::OnInitialUpdate()
{
    CView::OnInitialUpdate();
    pInputData = pOutputData = NULL;
    //...
}

void PinNameView::OnUpdate(CView* pSender, LPARAM lHint, CObject* pHint)
{
    //...
    this->Invalidate(false);
}
```

I have to set the variables `pInputData` and `pOutputData` to *`NULL`* before `OnUpdate()`,
but it's set to *`NULL`* after `OnUpdate()`

This `PinNameView` class is derived from `CView` class.

I want to know the reason why it's called first.

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense. The answer is as useless as it is obvious: The code behaves the way it does because it is written that way.

Comment: @IInspectable sorry, I made a big mistake! I wanted to know why pInputData set to NULL after OnUpdate() not CView::OnInitialUpdate() that I said before. The code CView::OnInitialUpdate(); above was on the first line in the function, MFC recommands us to type the code below CView::OnInitialUpdate(). But I think the function of OnInitialUpdate() might initialize the variables, and now I'm curious about the reason why it make go to OnUpdate() function in the middle of the function OnInitialUpdate(), which is I guess supposed to go after finishing all in OnInitialUpdate() ?

Comment: This explanation doesn't make things any clearer. You are stating assumptions, that are wrong, and then ask, why you wind up with behavior that the assumptions cannot explain. Please get yourself a copy of Jeff Prosise' [Programming Windows with MFC](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1572316950).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CView::OnInitialUpdate call CView::OnUpdate.

So if you OnUpdate implementation relies on variables that must be set in OnInitialUpdate, you have to do your init stuff first and then call the default implementation.

```
void PinNameView::OnInitialUpdate()
{
    pInputData = pOutputData = NULL;
    //...

    CView::OnInitialUpdate();
}
```

Comment: (For beginners like me) In this answer, "the *default* implementation" means the `CView::OnInitialUpdate()` (not *our* OnInitalUpdate). So the point is calling the CView::OnInitialUpdate() **after** the initialization stuff (in the OP's case `pInputData = pOutputData = NULL;`).